# Why Custom ArrayAdapter not showing TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have made a custom ArrayAdapter and tried to add the another TextView "Breed" of the animals, but when i execute the program , its not showing the Breed. Where am i doing wrong ? I am scratching my head since long. please help where is the mistake ?

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView simpleList;
    ArrayList<Item> animalList=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);


        animalList.add(new Item("Lion",R.drawable.lion,"Khatarnak"));
        animalList.add(new Item("Tiger",R.drawable.tiger,"Fudu"));
        animalList.add(new Item("Monkey",R.drawable.monkey,"Lallu"));
        animalList.add(new Item("Elephant",R.drawable.elephant,"Jabardast"));
        animalList.add(new Item("Dog",R.drawable.dog,"ItemDog"));
        animalList.add(new Item("Cat",R.drawable.cat,"MeeMee"));

        MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_view_items,animalList);
        simpleList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.Java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    ArrayList<Item> animalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        animalList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_items, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView breedView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.breed);

        textView.setText(animalList.get(position).getAnimalName());
        imageView.setImageResource(animalList.get(position).getAnimalImage());
        breedView.setText(animalList.get(position).getBreed());

        return v;

    }

}
```

Item.Java

```
public class Item {

    String animalName;
    int animalImage;
    String breedName;


    public String getBreed() {
        return breedName;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breedName = breedName;
    }

    public Item(String animalName,int animalImage,String breedName)
    {
        this.animalImage=animalImage;
        this.animalName=animalName;
        this.breedName = breedName;
    }
    public String getAnimalName()
    {
        return animalName;
    }
    public int getAnimalImage()
    {
        return animalImage;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_view_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Breed"
        android:textColor="#000" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with the linear layout for each item. The orientation is `horizontal`, which lays each view one after the other horizontally. The problem is that the text view for the animal type has a width of `fill_parent` leaving no space for the `breed` view. If you change it to `wrap_content` it'll probably work for some of the cases, but might not work with everything.

In any case I think this is a problem with the views' positions and sizes. Try and move them around. Perhaps even a simple change would be placing them vertically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />

  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#000" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Breed"
        android:textColor="#000" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

There's perhaps a more efficient way of doing this, but this is just an example. The inner linear layout places one text view on to of the other.

PS: your `getCount` method is not really doing anything. You can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**replace your layout with my code your issue will resolve.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Breed"
        android:textColor="#000" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have used a fill_parent that's why it is showing in full screen.